# get IBOutlets from xib file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

In my nib file I have several controls that I placed with xcode. Is there a way I can find how many outlets there are in the nib file. since I placed all the objects in the default view of the nib file maybe I can get the child of the default view and those will be the IBOutlets. I plan on latter adding functionality to those IBOUtlets.

In short I am trying to create a connection with code.... Thats cause I have so many objects in every nib file. I am creating an app that is like a power point presentation and I have several slides..

Comment: Question is not clear to me. you could have break your question with para or comma(,). :)

Comment: I'm confused... are you asking how to connect an IBOutlet from your code to an object on your NIB? If you right click on File's Owner in Interface Builder you should see a list of all the outlets found in your controller class. You just drag from the open circle next to the outlet of choice to whatever object it needs to be attached to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IBOutlets arent' actually anything.  That is just syntactical sugar to allow Interface Builder introspection into your code files to match up variable names.

Anyways, you can just look through all the subviews of your view in code if you need to.  Not ideal, but i think this is what you are asking for.

Answer (score 3):

```
SubclassedViewController *controller = [[SubclassedViewController alloc] 
    initWithNibName:@"SubclassedViewController" bundle:nil];

// actually, [[... alloc] init]; does the same

for (UIView *aView in [controller.view subviews]) {
    // do stuff
}
```

You could identify the Views with `tag`s, an integer properties that you can attach to any `UIView` (also in Interface Builder).